# How to set alias for nested object in SQL script generated from IQueryable

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, alias, iqueryable

I have an `IQueryable` from the database, which I map to view model like this:

```cs
IQueryable<ItemList> itemsList = query.Select(x =>
  new ItemList()
  {
      Phone = x.Phone,
      Email = x.Email,
      Fax = x.Fax,
      State = x.StateId.HasValue ? new GenericBox() { Text = x.State.Name , Value = x.State.Id } : null,
      Type = x.Type,
      ChildItems = x.Contact.ChildItems.OrderBy(a => a.Order).Select(a => new GenericBox() { Text = a.Child.FirstName + " " + a.Child.LastName, Value = a.ChildId })
  });
```

The GenericBox class is like this:

```cs
public class GenericBox
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Guid Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I transform this `IQueryable` to pure SQL and execute it with a `SqlCommand`.

The problem lies in the properties `State` and `ChildItems`.

I need to set alias for `State` properties `Text` and `Value`. Because `IQueryable` set them in the SQL with random generated names:

```sql
SELECT 
[Project3].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Project3].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
[Project3].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Project3].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
[Project3].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project3].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project3].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
[Project3].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Project3].[C5] AS [C3], 
[Project3].[C3] AS [C4], 
[Project3].[AgentId] AS [AgentId]
```

As you can see in the SELECT Name1 is for the State.Text from my class and C4 is for ChildItem.Text.

I need in the SELECT the alias for column Name1 to be Text for example. And the alias for Column C4 I want to be again Text.

Comment: Why do you care what the generated SQL is naming things?

Comment: When I read from SqlCommand later I need specific column and other not. And this should be very generic.

Comment: OK, so why are you executing it manually and not just using EF? That's very strange.

Comment: Because I work with great amount of Data. Thousands of records. And I use this approach because I do not want to load the data in the Memory. Imagine something like Reporting Application.

Comment: But why use EF at all? Just write your queries in SQL. Seems like you are making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I use EF a lot for other reason. I have for example 100 objects. I use the IQueriable part for all of them and its wokring perfectly. Now I want to re-use all the IQueriables which I already have for this approach. Otherwise I have to write new additional logic for all objects. And all that stops me is these alieses. And later I have to maintain both IQueriables and SQL for every change of an object.